# Use the on-board and the add-in video card at the same time?

Tags: graphics-card, display

I have an on-board NVIDIA video card (Analog connector) and an add-on video Radeon video card (Dual DVI connector).

Can I use both at the same time? The goal is to have 3 monitors in this workstation. I currently have 2 since I'm using the Radeon card. I want to use the Analog connector provided by the on-board video card to have three monitors.

EDIT:

I'm using a Dell Optiplex 755.

I've tried to boot with monitors attached to both output. The bios refused with a message "Video Card configuration not supported." and stopped me from booting into Windows.

Weird thing is, I have another Optiplex 755 with the ALMOST the same configuration and it can handle output on both on-board and add-in. The only difference between the two setup is that this the working machine's add-in card outputs to only a single DVI while the failing one outputs to a proprietary dell video output that splits the signal to two different monitors.

Comment: It all depends on the motherboard - which you haven't provided. Some motherboards disable the onboard graphics when a dedicated video card is plugged in, others leave it enabled.

Comment: Please see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have the latest Z series Intel chipset on your motherboard I seriously doubt that you will be able to use it in the way you intended.