# why does adding a video card disable on board video?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, motherboard

My understanding is that if I add a video card to a PC system that onboard (motherboard) video becomes unusable.

Why is that?
Is there a way to use both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use the on-board and the add-in video card at the same time?](http://superuser.com/questions/288338/use-the-on-board-and-the-add-in-video-card-at-the-same-time), [How can I enable onboard graphics AND dedicated card simultaneously?](http://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously) ...

Comment: @Karan except if he is asking *why* it disables, not how to use both... then the question should be OK and updated... But how to use both, yes you can google that or read your two articles.

Comment: @AthomSfere: Except the accepted answer to the second question I linked to above tells you why.

Comment: @Karan, but is the same or similar answer the same as the same question? I suppose a close as duplicate ultimately points to the old question...

Comment: @AthomSfere: "is the same or similar answer the same as the same question" - Huh? IMO the OP's query is answered by the linked questions, but if it isn't he's free to edit his question to clarify at any time.